# Как правильно передавать аргументы из DialogFragment в Fragment?

Tags: kotlin, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit, аргументы

Пишу приложение по работе с Yandex.Mapkit (карты).
Задача такая: надо по нажатию на карту в точке нажатия оставлять маркер(метку) с описанием объекта. Документация у Mapkit крайне скудная, не смог разобраться как оставлять маркер с описанием. Поэтому решил сделать по-другому.
При нажатии на карту, создаётся маркер (без описания) и открывается диалоговое окно, в котором пишу название маркера в поле EditText, нажимаю OK и передаю его в качестве аргумента во фрагмент из которого вызывалось диалоговое окно. А уже в этом фрагменте сохраняю координаты маркера и его описание в базу данных (Room), и на отдельном экране (Фрагмент с RecyclerView, в котором один item = описание одной метки).

Но после ввода текста в диалоге и нажатия ОК, почему-то сохраняется предыдущий аргумент (в итоге у первой записи в БД поле description пустое, у второй записи то, что я вводил в первый раз и т.д.)

Т.е.: В MapViewFragment в методе onMapLongTap() показываю диалоговое окно методом showDialog() и стартую корутину, в которой методом addMarker() добавляю метку на карту и сохраняю описание в базу данных (методом viewModel.save())
В MarkerNameDialogFragment в поле etDescription ввожу описание, и нажимаю ОК. А дальше, по идее, в MapViewFragment в этом месте

```
    override fun onFinishEditDialog(inputText: String) {
        description = inputText
    }
```

полю description должен передаться аргумент из EditText'а. Но он передаётся с задержкой.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем проблема...Ну или подскажите, как оставлять маркер с описанием сразу? (А лучше - и то, и другое).

Код диалогового окна:

```
class MarkerNameDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    interface MarkerNameDialogListener {
        fun onFinishEditDialog(inputText: String)
    }

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentDialogMarkerNameBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentDialogMarkerNameBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val title = "MarkerName"
        dialog?.setTitle(title)
        binding.etDescription.requestFocus()
        dialog?.window?.setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE
        )
        binding.btnCancel.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
        }

        binding.btnOk.setOnClickListener {
            sendBackResult()
        }
    }

    private fun sendBackResult() {
        val listener: MarkerNameDialogListener = targetFragment as MarkerNameDialogListener
        listener.onFinishEditDialog(binding.etDescription.text.toString())
        dismiss()
    }
}
```

Код Фрагмента, в котором это диалоговое окно показывается (убрал всё, что не относится к сути вопроса, оставил только самое необходимое):

```
class MapViewFragment : Fragment(),
    MarkerNameDialogFragment.MarkerNameDialogListener {

    private val viewModel: MarkerViewModel by viewModels(ownerProducer = ::requireParentFragment)

    companion object {
        var Bundle.textArg: String? by StringArg
    }

    private lateinit var mapView: MapView
    private lateinit var mapKit: MapKit
    private lateinit var userLocationLayer: UserLocationLayer
    private lateinit var mapObjectCollection: MapObjectCollection
    private lateinit var markerNameDialog: MarkerNameDialogFragment

    private var description: String = ""

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val binding = FragmentMapViewBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        mapView = binding.mapView

        mapKit = MapKitFactory.getInstance()
        mapKit.resetLocationManagerToDefault()

        userLocationLayer = mapKit.createUserLocationLayer(mapView.mapWindow)
        userLocationLayer.isVisible = true

        mapObjectCollection = mapView.map.mapObjects.addCollection()

        val listener = object : InputListener {
            override fun onMapLongTap(map: Map, point: Point) {
                showDialog()
                lifecycleScope.launch {
                    addMarker(
                        point.latitude, point.longitude,
                        R.drawable.mark, description
                    )
                }
            }

            override fun onMapTap(map: Map, point: Point) {
            }
        }
        mapView.map.addInputListener(listener)

        return binding.root
    }

    fun addMarker(
        lat: Double,
        lon: Double,
        @DrawableRes imageRes: Int,
        description: String
    ): PlacemarkMapObject {
        val marker = mapObjectCollection.addPlacemark(
            Point(lat, lon),
            ImageProvider.fromResource(
                requireContext(), imageRes
            )
        )
        viewModel.save(MarkerEntity(latitude = lat, longitude = lon, description = description))
        return marker
    }

    fun showDialog() {
        if (fragmentManager != null) {
            val fm = fragmentManager
            markerNameDialog = MarkerNameDialogFragment()
            markerNameDialog.setTargetFragment(this@MapViewFragment, 300)
            if (fm != null) {
                markerNameDialog.show(fm, "fragment_dialog_marker_name")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onFinishEditDialog(inputText: String) {
        description = inputText
    }

        override fun onStop() {
        mapView.onStop()
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop()
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart()
        mapView.onStart()
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем кидать данные туда-сюда? Почему не прокидывать координаты метки однократно после клика в диалоговое окно, а из него сразу сохранять в базу и координаты и описание?

Comment: @YaCor', спасибо большое, не подумал на счёт этого, теперь всё получилось!